# Tensorflow on Windows-10

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, gpu

Is GPU version of Tensorflow 0.12 running on Windows 10 stable? If not which is the most stable implementation for version 0.12?

Also when is Tensorflow 1.0 is due to be released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow 0.12.1 is currently (Jan. 2017) the latest "stable" release of TensorFlow for Windows. As this is the first version of TensorFlow released for Windows, there have been some bugs, and the `tf.contrib` libraries are not fully supported, but the core parts of the TensorFlow library are tested regularly and stable.

TensorFlow 1.0.0-alpha was [announced](https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&q=https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/d/msgid/discuss/CAKrkxF_fHRH1etTf%252BoNhHtETe%252BXKnD3kUrMS_Tqf22h4r%252BsK_g%2540mail.gmail.com?utm_medium%3Demail%26utm_source%3Dfooter&source=gmail&ust=1484409413162000&usg=AFQjCNEulIJie-_0UcB-W_47gqvN0SYuMw) earlier this week, but it is not yet available from PyPI, and official binary packages are not yet available. An announcement will be made soon about the release date for TensorFlow 1.0.0, and it will include a Windows package.

Comment: which version of Linux do you recommend?

Comment: I'd recommend using Windows if that fits in best with your existing workflow. For Linux I typically use Ubuntu 16.04, but I don't have a strong preference.